# How to obtain all TAction from a TActionManager?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, taction, tactionmanager

I have a `TActionManager` in my application, where all the actions are defined. I need to obtain a list of all its actions; currently, using its Actions property I can obtain the "path" for the action (`GetNamePath`) but I also want to obtain its caption.

Is it possible to obtain all actions from an action manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Actions[]` property returns a `TContainedAction` which is a low-level base class. You'll need to up-cast that to an appropriate derived class. For example, if your action manager contains `TAction` instances then you can do this:

```
for i := 0 to ActionManager1.ActionCount-1 do begin
  Writeln((ActionManager1.Actions[i] as TAction).Caption);
end;
```

If you are deriving custom actions from `TCustomAction`, then use that in your cast.

Obviously you might want to use `is` to check for the actual runtime type of the action and avoid a runtime cast error.

Comment: Ack - I thought I tried this and got some compile time admonishing, but probably I was doing something else wrong. Of course it works. Thank you very much.